# JLabel - On Mouse Entered change to a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, jtextfield

I have a JLabel with the text "Enter mouse" on it. As soon as the user enters the mouse on it I'd like a JTextField to be appeared so the user can search some things. If the mouse is removed then the previous JLabel has to appear again. I use:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ML extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ML() {
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(1, 2);
        setLayout(gl);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        jp.setLayout(cl);

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter mouse!");
        jp1.add(jl);

        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);
        jp2.add(jtf);

        jp.add(jp1, "1");
        jp.add(jp2, "2");
        cl.show(jp, "1");


        jp.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                cl.show(jp, "2");
            }
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt)
            {
                cl.show(jp, "1");
            }
        });

        add(jp);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

     }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ML();
            }
        });
    }}
```

Everything is working just fine but when I hover over JLabel "Enter mouse", it somewhat bugs/blinks between this and the JTextField. Why is that so and what can I do to fix it? Ty

Comment: I'd be use, to switch with true / false  to JTextField.setEnabled instead of CardLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it didn't glitch, it wouldn't work because the textfield is larger than the label, and you only add the listener to the label. The glitch is caused because only the textfield is being shown, therefore it fires the `mouseExited` event on the label. To solve this you want the `mouseEntered` event **only** on the label, but the `mouseExited` event **only** on the textfield.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ML extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ML() {
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(1, 2);
        setLayout(gl);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        jp.setLayout(cl);

        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter mouse!");
        jp1.add(jl);

        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);
        jp2.add(jtf);

        jp.add(jp1, "1");
        jp.add(jp2, "2");
        cl.show(jp, "1");

        jl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
                cl.show(jp, "2");
            }
        });

        jtf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
                cl.show(jp, "1");
            }
        });

        add(jp);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ML();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because when the `JTextField` is shown, the `mouseExited()` method is immediately called. Then of course the `JLabel` is shown again and this loops while you keep moving the mouse.

The following works:

```
    jl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
            cl.show(jp, "2");
        }
    });

    jtf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
            cl.show(jp, "1");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Damn, I was 4 seconds too late :D